# void method in Java Integration Tests

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit, integration-testing

I have some experience with Unit Tests in Java and now started to write Integration Tests. However, I have some troubles understanding the Integration Test and writing test. Here are some issues that I would like to be clarified:

**1.** In my Java (based on Spring Boot) project, should I write Integration Test for Controllers or may it be also ok to write Integration Test for Services also (because there are some methods that are not called from Controller).

**2.** How can I test a void in service by Integration Test? I have not found a proper example on the web and I thought there  is no need or way to test void via Integration Test. Any clarification pls?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so here are the best practices in the area.

> should I write Integration Test for Controllers or may it be also ok to write Integration Test for Services also

Most of the integration tests run for services. This is because each service can support several controllers and multiple interfaces in general. For controllers you do just the happy path tests on an integration level.

Any tests for controller specific exceptions go into the controller **unit** test, where you mock out the service.

> How can I test a void in service by Integration Test?

You check its side effect. For example, you use a `repository class` to see if the relevant data has been persisted to the database.

Does this solve your problem ? Let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for good explanations. Regarding to my question, I need to get more information about these points that do not seem to be clear t me :(

Comment: **1.** When we create Integration test, should we test the Controller methods or Service methods? Or both of them are ok?

Comment: Both. Most tests go on the service, though

Comment: If this answer has helped you, please feel free to upvote and mark it as accepted.

Comment: **2.** Your second answer is ok, I will test as you explained. On the other hand, in Unit Test, we test the method and functionality e.g. testing also if conditions by mocking the repository, etc. What about integration Tests? For it, we also test methods without mocking the repository, etc and retrieving data from repository (using in memory, but retrieving from repo). So, whould we still test the if conditions in Integration Tests as we do in unit tests?

Comment: By saying *"Most tests go on the service, though"*, do you mean that we should write Integration Test for Service method?

Comment: In integration tests we test that everything works together and integrates well.

Comment: Please also confirm the points that I ask in my questions.

Comment: What do you mean "*In integration tests we test that everything works together and integrates well.*"?

Comment: The primary point of an integration test is to test not the individual parts, but how well they intergrate together.

Comment: Any upvote for the question pls?